# Why won't aot compiler error on missing property?

Tags: angular, angular-aot

With the following code:

template

```
<button (click)="myMethod()">myMethod()</button>
<!-- <button (click)="foo()">foo()</button> -->

<ng-container [ngSwitch]="state">
  <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="0">
    <div></div>
    <button (click)="myMethod()">myMethod()</button>
    <button (click)="foo()">foo()</button><!-- why no error -->
  </ng-container>
  <div *ngSwitchCase="1"></div>
</ng-container>
```

component

```
export class MyComponent {

  public state = 0;

  public myMethod(): void {
    // no op
  }

}
```

`ng build --aot` builds, but if you uncomment the 2nd line in the template you expectedly get

> Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'MyComponent'.

Why does the `<button (click)="foo()">foo()</button>` inside the `ng-container` not error?

Before you suggest:

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="0">
  <div></div>
  <button (click)="myMethod()">myMethod()</button>
  <button (click)="foo()">foo()</button><!-- why no error -->
</div>
```

that will render as

```
<div>
  <div></div>
  <button>myMethod()</button>
  <button>foo()</button>
</div>
```

but I need just

```
<div></div>
<button>myMethod()</button>
<button>foo()</button>
```

And there are other ways around this, but the question is for fundamental understanding before making bug or feat.

Comment: I think this might be related to https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19792

Comment: AoT compiles the template beforehand, and is looking for the bindings to be generated. On the other hand, having it in an ng-container is a particular thing, since the ng-container will not be interpreted and thus compiled until it is called. 

See this article : https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet

Comment: Ahh so `ng-container` is not compiled at build time? If thats so, I'll accept that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Are there any other ways around this...?"

Have you tried this: https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#fulltemplatetypecheck ?

It looks like this AOT setting is (currently) inactive by default.

### Bonus:

Also see this section at compiler github on binding expressions: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/aio/content/guide/aot-compiler.md#phase-3-binding-expression-validation

> The validation uses the TypeScript type checker and the options supplied to the TypeScript compiler to control how detailed the type validation is

The error 'Property X does not exist on type Y' is thrown at this phase, and the level of validation detail is adjustable via compiler parameters, such as the aforementioned parameter 'fulltemplatetypecheck'.

Comment: Please let me know if this solves the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: Not sure how to set `fullTemplateTypeCheck` in angular cli project. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/12444#issuecomment-426352896 seems to imply it is already set to true on aot build.

Comment: Throws `Unknown compiler option 'angularCompilerOptions'.` if you set it in `tsconfig.json` but seems to work in `tsconfig.app.json`, just afraid to set `angularCompilerOptions` with all on the automagical stuff cli does

Comment: I don't think you should be afraid of the fulltemplatetypecheck paramter. The docs specifically say it will be `true` by default in the future. https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#fulltemplatetypecheck

It is my guess that this parameter was set to `false` by the dev team earlier in the life of the compiler for performance reasons.

Comment: I mean, by default `angularCompilerOptions` isn't even a part of `tsconfig.app.json` in a cli project. Setting it with one property for `fulltemplatetypecheck` works on simple duplication repo but how can I be confident that setting `angularCompilerOptions` won't overwrite any of the other compiler options or change the behavior of angular cli in unforeseen ways later on down the line or in a large production project. (been bitten by doing stuff like this in angular cli before)

Comment: Perhaps knowledge is power. You might feel better if you had a more in-depth understanding of the AOT compiler and how Angular uses tsconfig. If you want, you could do a comprehensive reading of the respective doc entries. 
https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration (tsconfig) https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#default-app-project-files (tsconfig.app.json)
https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler (AOT)

Comment: Its angular cli specifically I'm worried about. ie my `tsconfig.app.json` is not equal to what ngc gets

Comment: I'm over thinking though

Answer (score 1):

**This was my comment :**

AoT compiles the template beforehand, and is looking for the bindings to be generated. On the other hand, having it in an ng-container is a particular thing, since the ng-container will not be interpreted and thus compiled until it is called.

See this article :

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/

---

I tried searching more info into it, and I just went back to your first comment about the Angular issue :

From this thread https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20287 to this issue linked : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19792.

It seems to be an on-going bug, so that means that ng-containers are supposed to be compiled.
I guess there is nothing you can do about it for now !